# Quote Item option get lost after editing one item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I hope someone can help me...

The goal is to put products separated to the cart. So if 2 products with the same ID are in the cart, they should be shown and handle seperatly and not as one product/item with the qty 2.

To achieve this I use quote item options and events.

Event: checkout_cart_product_add_after 
Code:

```
     $quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
       array(
            'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
            'code' => 'unique_id',
           'value' => $uniqueId
      )
  ));
```

I also tried the same using addional_options:

```
   $additionalOptions = array(
            array(
                'code'  => 'unique_id',
                'label' => 'Uniaue ID',
                'value' => $uniqueId
            )
        );
    $quoteItem->addOption(
            array(
                'code'  => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
            )
        );
```

After that - everything works fine. The options are shown in the cart and they were stored into the database (sales_flat_quote_item_option) and they all have their own item-id.

But if I edit one product and put it again into the cart - the addional options get lost, they are no longer in the database... This affects all products with the same ID in the cart...

It will be nice, if someone can help me...

Comment: It's very helpfull to ask questions - often this is exactly the moment, the solution was found by myself... So - for your interest: The solution is to use the event:      catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options      $product->addCustomOption('unique_id', $uniqueId);

Comment: Please add it as the answer, it will be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

I had them same problem and used a whole different approach.
I made a module for it and added the following in config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>            
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- Model -->
                <quote>Companyname_Modulename_Model_Override_Mage_Sales_Model_Quote</quote>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
...
```

And created:

> app/code/community/Companyname/Modulename/Model/Override/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php

With the following code: (slightly edited from the original Magento code)

```
<?php
class Companyname_Modulename_Model_Override_Mage_Sales_Model_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
{
    /**
     * Adding catalog product object data to quote
     *
     * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
     */
    protected function _addCatalogProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
    {
        $newItem = false;
        $item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
        $item = false;
        if (!$item) {
            $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
            $item->setQuote($this);
            if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
                $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
            } else {
                $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            }
            $newItem = true;
        }

        /**
         * We can't modify existing child items
         */
        if ($item->getId() && $product->getParentProductId()) {
            return $item;
        }

        $item->setOptions($product->getCustomOptions())
            ->setProduct($product);

        // Add only item that is not in quote already (there can be other new or already saved item
        if ($newItem) {
            $this->addItem($item);
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

This way it forces every product to be added separated to the cart, this is specially nice if you add the option to place comments per product in your cart, then people add the same products with different comments.

I hope it helps someone else :)